# Stored Procedures or Not?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a PHP script which meets heavy load. It is a backend script for my smartphone game. In this script I do multiple inserts and selects with MySQL.

A) I was wondering if *Stored Procedures* could improve response and execution time?

B) Can I gain anything switching from MySQL to MySQLi in regards to response time? Or should I look for a completely different solution

Comment: have you done 'desc' on your queries to make sure they are indexed properly?

Comment: Well since mysql_* functions are going to be deprecated in the next major release, take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). It's prepared statements can improve performance. If you could post your current script, there might be a way to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures would move the complicated logic to the database part of your system, so you would effectively leverage work (and maybe a lot) by avoiding PHP from issuing a lot of inserts. If something that you do server-script-side can be ported to a stored procedure, it is likely to improve performance.

For the second question, you should move from mysql API to mysqli API since the mysql API [is already deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Why move from MySQLi to MySQL?

Comment: I have had some problems with "to many users" on mysql server. Would stored procedures help with this?

Comment: @JesperMansa depends on your problem, give more details or post a new question about your issue.

Comment: @Alec - OK thanks though. I was just looking for some general good practices with high traffic sites and multiple recordcalls...

Comment: @JesperMansa if you really care about performance then I suggest you to learn about stored procedures, triggers and such. They will really help you with high-traffic, data-intensive services.

Answer (score -2):

> I am wondering if Stored Procedures can do anything for me with response time and quick executing?

No.

> Can I gain anything going from mysql to mysqli in regards to response time?

No.

> or should I look in a another direction?

It is impossible to show you whatever direction knowing nothing of your particular situation.

As a general rule, multiple inserts can be optimized by removing indexes. Batch inserts can be possibly optimized by using transactions.